# How do i get Python to show all possible remainders instead of just the one that occurs with the largest multiple of the number?

Tags: python

Id like to find a way to see all possible remainders as a list if possible.

as an example instead of 34%5 yielding only 4 i'd like to implement a method that would yield a list of all possible remainders [29, 24, 19, 14, 9,4]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math 101 meets a generator:

```
def all_remainders(num, denom):
  value = num
  yield value # we want the original number 
  while value >= denom:
    value -= denom
    yield value
```

Does it work?

```
>>> list(all_remainders(34, 5))
[34, 29, 24, 19, 14, 9, 4]
>>> list(all_remainders(34, 17))
[34, 17, 0]
>>> _
```

I hope you understand the logic.

The `range`-based soluion by @dietrich-epp does the same, just using a standard function.

I'm not sure what exactly did you mean saying about repeated function application; here's my guess. If you want to apply the same function to its own output, you might do something like this:

```
result = []
for remainder in all_remainders(34, 5):
  for nested_remainder in all_remainders(remainder, 3):
    result.append(nested_remainder)

print result
```

But this will print a lot of repeating numbers. You can use a `set`, and even write the whole thing in one statement (it's called a 'generator comprehension'):

```
result = set(nested_remainder 
    for remainder in all_remainders(34, 5) 
    for nested_remainder in all_remainders(remainder, 7)
)

print result
```

Too bad the result is not going to be very interesting.

If you explained the problem you're solving, we might come with a better solution.

Comment: yes this is a bit more what i was looking for, now would i be able to recall that function and its list upon another divisor?

Comment: Hmm, the example shows the use of _two_ different divisors, namely `5` and `17`. As you might have guessed, `num` is the numerator and `denom` is the denominator aka divisor.

Comment: hmm well id like to have the original number in the list, and basically run the function over itself replacing num with the list of "remainders" and the original numbers. excuse my lack of knowledgeable jargon.

Comment: [`all_remainders = lambda num, denom: range(num, -1, -denom)`](http://ideone.com/0OsJlr)

Comment: hmm your right, seems like im more looking for a manner of which i can create a list of the result of subsequent subtraction and its results

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `range` function.

```
>>> print(list(range(34, 0, -5)))
[34, 29, 24, 19, 14, 9, 4]
```

(Although only 4 is the remainder.  There is only one true remainder.)

Comment: what im trying to say is all possible remainders of n/j*k, for instance [24%(5*1), 24%(5*2),...ect]

Comment: actually your answer was quite helpful once i looked at it a second time

Comment: [shouldn't it be `-1` instead of `0`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207188/how-do-i-get-python-to-show-all-possible-remainders-instead-of-just-the-one-that#comment17982871_13207245)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: If you're going to include 0, why stop there?  Why not include negative numbers?

Comment: @JordanAffonso: That is not what you asked for.  Using that formula, you would never get 19 from 34 and 5.  (You would get 4, 9, 14, and 34.)

Comment: because `0` is a valid remainder e.g., `34 % 17`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: And why isn't -17?

Comment: because `n % k >= 0` for positive integers `n`,`k` in Python.